# Does the google drive SDK for iOS support 64-bit architecture?

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create an iOS app that uses the google drive API. I have run through the quickstart guide (https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios) and have got it working for anything non-64 bit. I can plug in an iPad 2 and it works. But when I try to run it on an iPad air, I get the following error:

```
GTLTouchStaticLib was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libGTLTouchStaticLib.a' because its architectures 'armv7 armv7s' didn't contain all required architectures 'arm64'
```

I've tried changing the "Build Active Architecture Only" value in my build settings to both yes and no, but neither have worked. Am I missing something here? Or does this SDK not support 64-bit iOS devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it does not support 64-bit arm. You can solve this problem by simply not building for 64 bit. (The 32 bit version will work fine on 64 bit devices.)

All you need to do is to change the "Architectures" build setting from "Standard Architectures (including 64 bit)" to "Standard Architectures". Changing "Build Active Architecture Only" won't work, because when you're using a 64-bit device, that's the active architecture.

Comment: Thank you! I still get a warning message:

GTLTouchStaticLib was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libGTLTouchStaticLib.a' because its architectures 'armv7 armv7s' didn't contain all required architectures 'arm64'

Any idea what that means? Or if I need to worry about it?

Comment: That's exactly the same message you were seeing before, isn't it? It might be that you want to change the "Valid Architectures" setting as well.

Comment: Genius! It was the "valid architectures" setting as well. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to build your iOS app for 64-bit (which is now the default) you can do so by including the source files for the Google Drive SDK in your project and building them with 64-bit enabled (instead of using the static library).

Google has provided directions on how to do this here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/BuildingTheLibrary

(See the last section named "Compiling the Source Files Directly into a Mac or iOS Application")

With these steps I was able to build a Drive enabled iOS app for 64-bit architecture.